# How to store images in S3 in yii-framework

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, yii, amazon-s3

I m using yii framework and i m trying to upload images in S3.

Files were stored in the local server using CUploadedFile. I need to send new images in amazon because server is full.

Images are sent to s3 server but they are damaged and can t be opened.

**ArticleControllers.php**

```
public function actionCreate() {
  $model = new Article();
  if(isset($_POST['Article']) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Article']
    $model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
    $image = new Image();
    $uploadSuccess = $image->insertNewPicture($model->image);
    if ($uploadSuccess)
      $model->save();
  }
}
```

**Image.php**

```
public function insertNewPicture($image) {
  if (empty($image))
    return false;

  $s3Client = S3Client::factory(Yii::app()->params['s3']);
  try {
     $success = $s3Client->upload('my_bucket', 
     'test.png', fopen($image->getTempName(), 'rb'),
    'public-read');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$success)
        return false;
   return $this->save();
}
```

I also tried file_get_contents($image->getTempName()) but i don't know what is wrong....